# How to run a local AWS Lambda container as part of a docker compose?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm having a huge headache figuring this out, I just want to emulate a local AWS Lambda service to easily test integration without writing custom clients and such

I have this monorepo:

```
 | lambda-service-emulator/
 ---| app.py
 ---| Dockerfile
 | lambda-function/
 ---| Dockerfile
 | docker-compose.yml
```

lambda-service-emulator/app.py its a very simple FastAPI, with a single endpoint to simulate Lambda Service API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Header
import os
import requests

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/2015-03-31/functions/{function_name}/invocations")
def invoke_lambda(
    function_name: str,
    payload: dict = Body({})
):
    f_endpoint = os.environ['FUNCTION_ENDPOINT']
    r = requests.post(f'{f_endpoint}/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations', json=payload)
    try:
        data = r.json()
    except Exception:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400
        }
    return data
```

lambda-function/Dockerfile its an image that is compliant with AWS Lambda

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided as runtime
# installing stuff
CMD ["handler.handler"]
```

And the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  lambda-service:
    build: ./lambda-service-emulator
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      FUNCTION_ENDPOINT: http://lambda-function:8080
  lambda-function:
     volumes:
       - ./lambda-function:/var/task
    build: ./lambda-function
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
```

Here's the problem, when I try to invoke the lambda through compose, the code goes through normally, but before it can return the response, it gives this error:

> [ERROR] (rapid) Failed to reserve: AlreadyReserved

I think its because this image is not meant to keep running, it should teardown after every invocation, but I'm not sure how to solve this while maintaining the docker compose strutcture?

It works if I run the container as a one off, as per this docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html

Comment: Lambda compatible docker images are not designed to be torn down after every invocation. Even in AWS the image will be kept running and reused for many invocations if you have active requests coming in. So that is not the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699358/aws-lambda-error-rapid-failed-to-reserve-alreadyreserved

Comment: Hmm, maybe its a memory limit issue then? I just noticed it printed `REPORT RequestId: 04d5802e-7931-4f21-a962-470d9d235312  Init Duration: 0.38 ms  Duration: 72223.98 ms   Billed Duration: 72224 ms       Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB` at the end